# How does one declare optional methods in a Swift protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, optional-parameters, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Is it possible in Swift? If not then is there a workaround to do it?

Comment: In case future readers are looking for it, here is the discussion of [optional protocol requirements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols#Optional-Protocol-Requirements) from [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language).

Answer (score 658, accepted):

#### 1. Using default implementations (preferred).

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        /* return a default value or just leave empty */
    }
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    /* no compile error */
}
```

**Advantages**

- **No Objective-C runtime is involved** (well, no explicitly at least). This means you can conform structs, enums and non-`NSObject` classes to it. Also, this means you can take advantage of powerful generics system.
- **You can always be sure that all requirements are met** when encountering types that conform to such protocol. It's always either concrete implementation or default one. This is how "interfaces" or "contracts" behave in other languages.

**Disadvantages**

- **For non-`Void` requirements, you need to have a reasonable default value**, which is not always possible. However, when you encounter this problem, it means that either such requirement should really have no default implementation, or that your you made a mistake during API design.
- **You can't distinguish between a default implementation and no implementation at all**, at least without addressing that problem with special return values. Consider the following example:

  ```swift
  protocol SomeParserDelegate {
      func validate(value: Any) -> Bool
  }
  ```

  If you provide a default implementation which just returns `true` — it's fine at the first glance. Now, consider the following pseudo code:

  ```swift
  final class SomeParser {
      func parse(data: Data) -> [Any] {
          if /* delegate.validate(value:) is not implemented */ {
              /* parse very fast without validating */
          } else {
              /* parse and validate every value */
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  There's no way to implement such an optimization — you can't know if your delegate implements a method or not.

  Although there's a number of different ways to overcome this problem (using optional closures, different delegate objects for different operations to name a few), that example presents the problem clearly.

---

#### 2. Using `@objc optional`.

```swift
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    @objc optional func doSomething()
}

class MyClass: NSObject, MyProtocol {
    /* no compile error */
}
```

**Advantages**

- **No default implementation is needed.** You just declare an optional method or a variable and you're ready to go.

**Disadvantages**

- **It severely limits your protocol's capabilities** by requiring all conforming types to be Objective-C compatible. This means, only classes that inherit from `NSObject` can conform to such protocol. No structs, no enums, no associated types.
- **You must always check if an optional method is implemented** by either optionally calling or checking if the conforming type implements it. This might introduce a lot of boilerplate if you're calling optional methods often.

Comment: Because "optional requirement" (which is an oxymoron itself) goes against the idea of contract + prevents static dispatch. One of the Swift Core Team members (I don't remember who that was exactly) said that Swift only has "optional protocol requirements" because it is needed for Obj-C interop. Also, the idea of native "optional requirements" was quickly discarded in the early days of swift-evolution.

Answer (score 416):

In Swift 2 and onwards it's possible to add default implementations of a protocol. This creates a new way of optional methods in protocols.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomethingNonOptionalMethod()
    func doSomethingOptionalMethod()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func doSomethingOptionalMethod(){ 
        // leaving this empty 
    }
}
```

It's not a really nice way in creating optional protocol methods, but gives you the possibility to use structs in in protocol callbacks.

I wrote a small summary here:
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift-2-0/optional-protocol-methods/

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do it in Swift. Too bad it does not work prior to Swift 2.0.

Comment: @MattQuiros I'm finding that you do in fact need to declare the function in the protocol definition, otherwise the no-op extension function doesn't get overridden in your classes that conform to the protocol.

Comment: @IanPearce is correct, and this appears to be by design. In the "Protocol Oriented Programming" talk (408) at WWDC, they talk about methods in the main protocol being "customization points" offered to conforming types. A required point of customization doesn't receive a definition in an extension; an optional point does. Methods on the protocol that generally should not be customized are wholly declared/defined in the extension to disallow conforming types to customize *unless you specifically cast down to its dynamicType* to show you want the conformer's custom implementation.

Comment: Good writeup of the subtlety in dynamic dispatch to protocol or implementing class here:  http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_203

Comment: But in this way you can not check if the method is implemented or not (it always is, but empty). The delegate source in real life checks if the delegate implements the selector or not and then according to the result does different things.

Comment: @Darko, in that case I think you can enable the optional method to throw `MethodNotImplementedError` or something similar (as in Java).

Comment: @FranklinYu You can do this but then you are poluting your API design with 'throws' where it's in fact not needed. I like more the idea of "micro protocols". E.g. each method confirms to one protocol and then you can check for: if object is protocol

Comment: So in other words you provide its implementation in the extension through defaulting it. However since the implementation is empty, ie it has no code, you can *think* of it as an optional method?

Comment: @Antoine I think you should make the function in the extension public, since the functions in the protocols are public by definition. Your solution will not work when the protocol will be used outside of its module.

Answer (score 43):

**Here is a concrete example with the delegation pattern.**

Setup your Protocol:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol:class
{
    func requiredMethod()
    optional func optionalMethod()
}

class MyClass: NSObject
{
    weak var delegate:MyProtocol?

    func callDelegate()
    {
        delegate?.requiredMethod()
        delegate?.optionalMethod?()
    }
}
```

Set the delegate to a class and implement the Protocol. See that the optional method does not need to be implemented.

```
class AnotherClass: NSObject, MyProtocol
{
    init()
    {
        super.init()

        let myInstance = MyClass()
        myInstance.delegate = self
    }

    func requiredMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

One important thing is that the optional method is optional and needs a "?" when calling. Mention the second question mark.

```
delegate?.optionalMethod?()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Simple, clean and explanatory.

Answer (score 40):

Since there are some answers about how to use **optional modifier** and **@objc attribute** to define optional requirement protocol, I will give a sample about how to use protocol extensions define optional protocol.

Below code is Swift 3.*.

```
/// Protocol has empty default implementation of the following methods making them optional to implement:
/// `cancel()`
protocol Cancelable {

    /// default implementation is empty.
    func cancel()
}

extension Cancelable {

    func cancel() {}
}

class Plane: Cancelable {
  //Since cancel() have default implementation, that is optional to class Plane
}

let plane = Plane()
plane.cancel()
// Print out *United Airlines can't cancelable*
```

Please notice protocol extension methods can't invoked by Objective-C code, and worse is Swift team won't fix it. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-492

Comment: Good job! This should be the correct answer since it solves the problem without getting Objective-C runtime involved.

Comment: from swift documentation - "Protocol requirements with default implementations provided by extensions are distinct from optional protocol requirements. Although conforming types don’t have to provide their own implementation of either, requirements with default implementations can be called without optional chaining."

Answer (score 36):

The other answers here involving marking the protocol as "@objc" do not work when using swift-specific types.

```
struct Info {
    var height: Int
    var weight: Int
} 

@objc protocol Health {
    func isInfoHealthy(info: Info) -> Bool
} 
//Error "Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C"
```

In order to declare optional protocols that work well with swift, declare the functions as variables instead of func's.

```
protocol Health {
    var isInfoHealthy: (Info) -> (Bool)? { get set }
}
```

And then implement the protocol as follows

```
class Human: Health {
    var isInfoHealthy: (Info) -> (Bool)? = { info in
        if info.weight < 200 && info.height > 72 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    //Or leave out the implementation and declare it as:  
    //var isInfoHealthy: (Info) -> (Bool)?
}
```

You can then use "?" to check whether or not the function has been implemented

```
func returnEntity() -> Health {
    return Human()
}

var anEntity: Health = returnEntity()

var isHealthy = anEntity.isInfoHealthy(Info(height: 75, weight: 150))? 
//"isHealthy" is true
```

Comment: With this solution you can't access self from within any of the protocol functions. This may cause issues in some cases!

Comment: @GeorgeGreen You can access self. Mark the function variable as lazy and use a [capture list inside the closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_100).

Comment: Only classes, protocols, methods and properties can use @objc. In case you are using an Enum parameter in the @ objc protocol method defination, you are doomed.

Comment: @khunshan, this method requires nothing being marked @ objc, what are you referring to?

Comment: its an information on the topic that enums cannot be used in between swift and objc which the for other statements can be bridged with @objc keyword.

Comment: For the first error you mentionned, you need to make the protocol as a subclass of NSObject: `@objc protocol Health: AnyObject {...`

Answer (score 35):

In **Swift 3.0**

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    @objc optional func increment(forCount count: Int) -> Int
    @objc optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}
```

It will save your time.

Comment: Any source of why `@objc` is needed on all members now?

Comment: @Gautam Sareriya: What do you think is best this approach or creating empty extension methods?

Comment: I tried with your methods with `required` flag, but with errors: `required` may only be used on 'init' declarations.

Answer (score 29):

- You need to add `optional` keyword prior to each method.
- Please note, however, that for this to work, **your protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute.**
- This further implies that this protocol would be applicable to classes but not structures.

Comment: Minor correction (too small to edit!) but it should be 'optional' not '@optional'

Comment: This also requires you to mark your class implementing the protocol as `@objc`, not just the protocol.

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways you can create optional method in swift protocol.

1 - The first option is to mark your protocol using the @objc attribute. While this means it can be adopted only by classes, it does mean you mark individual methods as being optional like this:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    @objc optional func optionalMethod()
}
```

2 - A swiftier way: This option is better. Write default implementations of the optional methods that do nothing, like this.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func optionalMethod()
    func notOptionalMethod()
}

extension MyProtocol {

    func optionalMethod() {
        //this is a empty implementation to allow this method to be optional
    }
}
```

Swift has a feature called extension that allow us to provide a default implementation for those methods that we want to be optional.

Answer (score 14):

A pure Swift approach with protocol inheritance:

```
//Required methods
protocol MyProtocol {
    func foo()
}

//Optional methods
protocol MyExtendedProtocol: MyProtocol {
    func bar()
}

class MyClass {
    var delegate: MyProtocol
    func myMethod() {
        (delegate as? MyExtendedProtocol).bar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To illustrate the mechanics of Antoine's answer:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func aMethod()
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    func aMethod() {
        print("extensionImplementation")
    }
}

class protocolImplementingObject: SomeProtocol {

}

class protocolImplementingMethodOverridingObject: SomeProtocol {
    func aMethod() {
        print("classImplementation")
    }
}

let noOverride = protocolImplementingObject()
let override = protocolImplementingMethodOverridingObject()

noOverride.aMethod() //prints "extensionImplementation"
override.aMethod() //prints "classImplementation"
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that before asking **how** you can implement an optional protocol method, you should be asking **why** you should implement one.

If we think of swift protocols as an *Interface* in classic object oriented programming, optional methods do not make much sense, and perhaps a better solution would be to create default implementation, or separate the protocol into a set of protocols (perhaps with some inheritance relations between them) to represent the possible combination of methods in the protocol.

For further reading, see https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-optional-protocol-methods/, which gives an excellent overview on this matter.

Comment: This. It's adherence to the ["I"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) principle in the [**SOLID** software development principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Answer (score 7):

Slightly off topic from the original question, but it builds off Antoine’s idea and I thought it might help someone.

You can also make computed properties optional for structs with protocol extensions.

You can make a property on the protocol optional

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var required: String { get }
    var optional: String? { get }
}
```

Implement the dummy computed property in the protocol extension

```
extension SomeProtocol {
    var optional: String? { return nil }
}
```

And now you can use structs that do or don’t have the optional property implemented

```
struct ConformsWithoutOptional {
    let required: String
}

struct ConformsWithOptional {
    let required: String
    let optional: String?
}
```

I’ve also written up how to do [optional properties in Swift protocols on my blog](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2015/08/29/optional-computed-property-swift-protocol-non-objc/), which I’ll keep updated in case things change through the Swift 2 releases.

Answer (score 5):

**How to create optional and required delegate methods.**

```
@objc protocol InterViewDelegate:class {

    @objc optional func optfunc()  //    This is optional
    func requiredfunc()//     This is required 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple example for swift Classes ONLY, and not for structures or enumerations.
Note that the protocol method being optional, has two levels of optional chaining at play. 
Also the class adopting the protocol needs the @objc attribute in its declaration.

```
@objc protocol CollectionOfDataDelegate{
   optional func indexDidChange(index: Int)
}


@objc class RootView: CollectionOfDataDelegate{

    var data = CollectionOfData()

   init(){
      data.delegate = self
      data.indexIsNow()
   }

  func indexDidChange(index: Int) {
      println("The index is currently: \(index)")
  }

}

class CollectionOfData{
    var index : Int?
    weak var delegate : CollectionOfDataDelegate?

   func indexIsNow(){
      index = 23
      delegate?.indexDidChange?(index!)
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you describe a little more the "_two levels of optional at play_" part, namely this: `delegate?.indexDidChange?(index!)`?

Comment: If we had written the protocol to have a non optional method like this: 

`protocol CollectionOfDataDelegate{
        func indexDidChange(index: Int)
}`

then you would call it without the question mark:

`delegate?.indexDidChange(index!)`

When you set a optional requirement for a method in a protocol, the Type that will conform to it might NOT implement that  method, so the `?` is used to check for the implementation and If there is none the program will not crash. @Unheilig

Comment: `weak var delegate : CollectionOfDataDelegate?` (ensure weak reference?)

Comment: @BlessingLopes Can you add your explanation of the `delegate?` usage to your answer? That information should really belong in there for others in the future. I want to upvote this, but that information should really be in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do it in pure swift the best way is to provide a default implementation particullary if you return a Swift type like for example  **struct** with Swift types

example :

```
struct magicDatas {
    var damagePoints : Int?
    var manaPoints : Int?
}

protocol magicCastDelegate {
    func castFire() -> magicDatas
    func castIce() -> magicDatas
}

extension magicCastDelegate {
    func castFire() -> magicDatas {
        return magicDatas()
    }

    func castIce() -> magicDatas {
        return magicDatas()
    }
}
```

then you can implement protocol without defines every **func**

Answer (score 0):

To define `Optional` `Protocol` in swift you should use `@objc` keyword before `Protocol` declaration and `attribute`/`method` declaration inside that protocol.
Below is a sample of Optional Property of a protocol.

```
@objc protocol Protocol {

  @objc optional var name:String?

}
```

// Now if try to implement that protocol inside our code that will not force to include that function inside our class.

```
class MyClass: Protocol {

   // No error

}
```

Another way is to use protocol extension we can also give default implementation of that protocol. So that that functional of that protocol will make optional.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: Hi @RoshanaPitigala i have edited my Answer. I have give proper explanation for how to make optional.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store them as optional function variables:

```
struct MyAwesomeStruct {
    var myWonderfulFunction : Optional<(Int) -> Int> = nil
}

let squareCalculator =
    MyAwesomeStruct(myWonderfulFunction: { input in return input * input })
let thisShouldBeFour = squareCalculator.myWonderfulFunction!(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let's understand the difference first**

**First example -** If you write `UITableViewDataSource` then you need to write two method forcefully - That's the swift way default Protocol

**Second Example -** If you write `UITableViewDelegate` and aware that it doesn't show the red error that please add all the delegate method. It's up to you that which method you want to use. we can called as `optional method`!

Let's understand this by an example

**First Swift Way default Protocol approach**

```
class ContactModel{
    var firstname: String?
    var lastname: String?
}

protocol ContactDataSource: AnyObject{
    func contactConfiguration(contact: ContactModel)
}

class ViewController: ContactDataSource{
    func contactConfiguration(contact: ContactModel) {
        print(contact)
    }
}
```

**Second approach - optional protocol**

```
@objc
class UserModel: NSObject{
    var firstname: String = ""
}

@objc protocol UserDataSource{
    func contactConfiguration(user: UserModel)
   @objc optional func userInfo(user: UserModel)
}

class ViewController: UserDataSource{
    func contactConfiguration(user: UserModel) {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

> **Note: If you can see in optional protocal I haven't write userInfo method so its up to you. That mean With and without adding a method to the class
> its working fine. - called as a optional method in protocol**
>
> You must declare the class and protocol with the
> @objc attribute, and it's only working with Class not struct!

**Third approach - optional protocol using Extension**

> Note: You can take Struct or Class

```
class UserModel{
    var firstname: String = ""
}
```

**OR**

```
struct UserModel{
    var firstname: String = ""
}
```

**AND**

```
protocol UserDataSource{
    func contactConfiguration(user: UserModel)
}

extension UserDataSource{
    func userInfo(user: UserModel){}
}

class myview: UserDataSource{
    func contactConfiguration(user: UserModel) {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define function in protocol and create extension for that protocol, then create empty implementation for function which you want to use as optional.