# Delegate inside another class

Tags: swift, delegates, sprite-kit

Im trying to assign a delegate of a node inside another class, but its not working.

Example:

Class A:

```
import SpriteKit

protocol ClassADelegate {

    func testA() -> Bool

}

class ClassA: SKSpriteNode {


}
```

Class B:

```
 import SpriteKit

    protocol ClassBDelegate {

        func testB() -> Bool

    }

    class ClassB: SKSpriteNode {

       let aux = ClassA()
       aux.delegate = self
    }
```

So my problem is when i try to initialize the aux delegate. I already tried aux.delegate = ClassADelegate but that dont work either. It says i cant Assign a value of type ClassADelegate.protocol to ClassADelegate.

Any solution? Thanks.

Ps.: This is a very simple example and i know it dont result in anything. My problem is just with the delegate declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a whole bunch of problems.

First, `ClassA` doesn't have a property called `delegate`. Add that:

```
class ClassA: SKSpriteNode {
    var delegate : ClassADelegate?
}
```

Second, you can't just throw code randomly in the middle of a class. It has to go in a method, so move `aux.delegate = self` to an initializer:

```
class ClassB: SKSpriteNode {

    let aux = ClassA()

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        aux.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Third, `ClassB` does not conform to `ClassADelegate`. Declare that it does:

```
class ClassB: SKSpriteNode, ClassADelegate {
```

Fourth, `ClassB` does not implement the methods required by `ClassADelegate`, in this case `TestA()`. So add that:

```
func testA() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Finally, add the required initializer to `ClassB`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Here's the final code that will work:

```
protocol ClassADelegate {

    func testA() -> Bool

}

class ClassA: SKSpriteNode {
    var delegate : ClassADelegate?
}

protocol ClassBDelegate {

    func testB() -> Bool

}

class ClassB: SKSpriteNode, ClassADelegate {

    let aux = ClassA()

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        aux.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func testA() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i tried to make the code as simple as possible but i guess i made a wrong move. haha Thx =)

Comment: But i still have one doubt, what if i didnt want to use the testA function in the Class B and instead i wanted to use that function in another class, is that possible? Like i wanted to call funcA in my scene instead of my Class B.

Comment: Sure… just make your scene also conform to `ClassADelegate`

Comment: But the problem is that my ClassA will require that i implement my testA even if i dont want to since i just want to create my node, not implement all his functions.

Comment: Then make it optional in class A's delegate definition

Comment: How? I think that is my question after all.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. Im still having some troubles with crash but i'll try to figure that out. You gave me the right path.