# didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been trying to develop full featured music application in Swift.I was trying to check out available open source music app written in swift.I found an useful music application([ESTMusicPlayer](https://github.com/Aufree/ESTMusicPlayer))  but this application is written in objective-C.

I have almost replaced Objective-C version of MusicListViewContorller.h and MusicListViewContorller.m file with  MusicListViewContorller.swift using Swift Interpolablity and Mix-Match features.

I have converted Objective-C version:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playMusicWithSpecialIndex:)]) {
        [_delegate playMusicWithSpecialIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        MusicViewController *musicVC = [MusicViewController sharedInstance];
        musicVC.musicTitle = self.navigationItem.title;
        musicVC.musicEntities = _musicEntities;
        musicVC.specialIndex = indexPath.row;
        musicVC.delegate = self;
        [self presentToMusicViewWithMusicVC:musicVC];
    }
    [self updatePlaybackIndicatorWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**To:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    delegate?.playMusicSpecial(indexPath.row)

    self.updatePlayBackIndicatorWithIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

1. What will be equivalent Piece of codes for the following codes in Swift?

   ```
   if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playMusicWithSpecialIndex:)]) {
       [_delegate playMusicWithSpecialIndex:indexPath.row];
   }
   ```
2. What is alternative code for `respondToSelector:` in swift ?

Comment: For your 2nd question check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector

Comment: Have a look at What is the swift equivalent of respondsToSelector?( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167791/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-respondstoselector)

Comment: I have checked out the question link but i still have confusion.None of the answer from that question helped me out of problem i'm facing here. What about first question i have asked here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check by [Optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) that delegate implement particular method or not. To perform optional chaining method should be of optional type.

You can define optional method in protocol as given.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol:class
{
    func requiredMethod()
    optional func playMusicWithSpecialIndex(index : int)
}
```

Please check this link for [Optional Method declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol) in Protocol.

Try this code. This may help you.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if _delegate.playMusicWithSpecialIndex?(indexPath.row) {

    //Method Exist

}else{

    var musicVC: MusicViewController = MusicViewController.sharedInstance()
    musicVC.musicTitle = self.navigationItem.title
    musicVC.musicEntities = musicEntities
    musicVC.specialIndex = indexPath.row
    musicVC.delegate = self
    self.presentToMusicViewWithMusicVC(musicVC)
}
    self.updatePlaybackIndicatorWithIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: When i tried to implement your code i get compile error in: 

if _delegate.playMusicWithSpecialIndex?(indexPath.row) {

    //Method Exist

}

Xcode accepts following codes:

 if ((delegate!.playMusicSpecial?(indexPath.row)) != nil) {
  
            //Method Exist
            
        }

Why Compiler doesn't accept the code you mentioned in your code?

Comment: Method declaration should be of optional type.

Comment: Your issue fixed or not ?

Comment: I still have an issue with  musicVC.musicEntities = musicEntities line. I have declared musicEntites as [MusicEntity]() Array variable. But when i'm trying to set Swift array to Objective-C Mutable array then it isn't working. I have tried to us as? keword for casting it to [AnyObject] but it didn't work. How can i convert an Swift Array type of object to Objective C type of Array? Do you have any idea? or Should i post another question related to this problem?