# Optional Protocol Method in a Cocoapod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, protocols

I have several protocol methods that a develop can call as delegates when they install my cocoapod. However, they are currently all required to be implemented. How do I go about making them optional? Here's a snippet of one:

In my cocoapod's code:

```
public protocol ServiceDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didDetectDoubleTapGesture()
}

//To fire the protocol method...
delegate?.didDetectDoubleTapGesture()
```

From the developer's side:

```
extension ViewController: ServiceDelegate {

    func didDetectDoubleTapGesture() {
        print("didDetectDoubleTapGesture")
    }

}
```

It currently works, but I want to make it optional for the developer to have to implement the 'didDetectDoubleTapGesture()' delegate method. So far I have tried '@objc' and '@optional'. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: `@optional` means optional. What isn't "clean" about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define optional methods in Swift protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to use optional methods, you must mark your protocol with @objc attribute:

@objc protocol ServiceDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
   @objc optional func didDetectDoubleTapGesture()
}

//To fire the protocol method...
delegate?.didDetectDoubleTapGesture()

extension ViewController: ServiceDelegate {

//no error
}

************************** or **********************
public protocol ServiceDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didDetectDoubleTapGesture()
}

//To fire the protocol method...
delegate?.didDetectDoubleTapGesture()

extension ServiceDelegate {
    func didDetectDoubleTapGesture()
}

extension ViewController: ServiceDelegate {

//no error
}
```