# Non-'@objc' method does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I've put the following into a Playground to try and understand this and I just don't:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol Sample {

    var value: Int { get set }

    func increase()
    func decrese()

}

extension Sample {

    func increase() {
        value += 1
    }

    func decrease() {
        value -= 1
    }

}

class Test: Sample {

    var value: Int = 0

}
```

The error appears next to the `class` declaration for `Test` saying:

> Non-'@objc' method 'increase()' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'Sample'

If I re-declare `increase()` and `decrease()` in the class then the warning is silenced. Or also if I remove the declarations from the protocol. Could someone please explain?

**EDIT**

I do need an Objective-C class to conform to this protocol as well, hence the `@objc` at the start.

Comment: You are providing default implementation for Swift scope only. As you protocol is `@objc` your `Test` class don't see default implementation

Comment: Since you used @-objc, when you implement a protocol, you need to implement its methods in the class you conform the protocol. Also you might want to use @objc optional for the methods you don't want to implement in the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define optional methods in Swift protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you’re defining these methods in a protocol extension. This is used to define a “default implementation” for a protocol (i.e. if a type doesn’t implement the method, the protocol’s implementation will be called).

But Objective-C doesn’t have the concept of default implementations for protocols. So it doesn’t makes sense to declare the protocol as `@objc` and have default implementations within the Swift protocol extension. An Objective-C class conforming to this protocol would never be able to enjoy these Swift default implementations.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487168/non-objc-method-does-not-satisfy-optional-requirement-of-objc-protocol

Answer (score 0):

The below code works with empty protocol methods' implementation in the Protocol extension class

```
import Foundation

protocol Sample {
    var value: Int { get set }
    func increase()
    func decrease()
}

extension Sample {
    func increase() { }
    func decrease() { }
}

class Test: Sample {
    var value: Int = 0
}
```

or if you want some default implementation of `Sample` protocol methods in the extension then use

```
import Foundation

protocol Sample {
    var value: Int { get set }

    func increase()
    mutating func decrease()
}

extension Sample {
    func increase() {
        print("do anything")
    }

    mutating func decrease() {
        value -= 1
    }
}

class Test: Sample {
    var value: Int = 0
}
```

`mutating` is added before the protocol method `decrease()` because it modifies the Protocol variable `value`.
If the Protocol extension doesn't modify any of the Protocol variable (e.g. `increase()`), then there is no need of `mutating` keyword

Comment: It works no problem when the protocol isn't declared `@objc`, but as I stated, I need it to be accessible to ObjC. @Rob is right though. ObjC doesn't know anything about protocol extensions, hence the need to redeclare the implementations