# Question about Delegate / Protocol requirements

Tags: swift

So I just made my ViewController conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

They way I understand it is:

A `Delegate` is simply a protocol. Protocols have some requirements, in the case of `UITextFieldDelegate` some of them would look like..

```
protocol UITextFieldDelegate: class { 
     var delegate: (Not sure of this type actually) { get set }
    
     func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) 

     func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)

     //etc, etc.
}
```

Why did I get no compile errors when I hadn't implemented any of the methods? Are they some how not required or does UIViewController implicitly already conform to these methods?

Comment: Because they are `optional`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting It's more a Objective-C way, since in theory a protocol method can't be optional. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-make-optional-protocol-methods or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is not quite how `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol is defined. Two observations:

- The text field delegate protocol does not include a `delegate` property.

  Yes, the text field has a `delegate` property:

  ```swift
  @available(iOS 2.0, *)
  open class UITextField : UIControl, UITextInput, NSCoding, UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting {

      ...

      weak open var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? // default is nil. weak reference

      ...
  }
  ```

  But the delegate protocol has no requirement for a `delegate` property in the view controller (or whatever you specify as the delegate).
- The methods are `optional`.

  The actual definition is as follows (found by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> or “File” » “Open Quickly...”, making sure the Swift button is selected, and then searching for `UITextFieldDelegate`):

  ```swift
  public protocol UITextFieldDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

      @available(iOS 2.0, *)
      optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool // return NO to disallow editing.

      @available(iOS 2.0, *)
      optional func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) // became first responder

      @available(iOS 2.0, *)
      optional func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool // return YES to allow editing to stop and to resign first responder status. NO to disallow the editing session to end

      @available(iOS 2.0, *)
      optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) // may be called if forced even if shouldEndEditing returns NO (e.g. view removed from window) or endEditing:YES called

      ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C protocols (resp. protocols that inherit from `NSObjectProtocol`) can declare their requirements `optional`. In fact, most delegates will declare all methods `optional`. This means that you won't have to implement the methods, when you choose not to do so some default behavior is implemented.